# Urls for sending OpenTelemetry traces to grafana-agent urls

Tags: open-telemetry, grafana-agent

When sending traces to tempo I use `http://<tempo ip>:4318/v1/traces`, what is the path for sending traces to grafana-agent. I see nothing in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint is the same, i.e. `http://<grfana agent ip>:4318/v1/traces` - but the grafana agent has to be configured for OpenTelemetry as described in [Grafana Agent configuration for OpenTelemetry](https://grafana.com/docs/opentelemetry/instrumentation/grafana-agent/).

You can also use the [OpenTelemetry integration](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/data-configuration/integrations/integration-reference/integration-opentelemetry/) for Grafana Cloud, which will generate a ready-to-use Grafana agent configuration for you.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have been trying to push to tempo-host:3200 and its various query endpoint and also tempo-host:4318 and its various endpoint and failing with 404. `tempo-host:4318/v1/traces` works! This is truly not clear in grafana tempo documentation.